# How can I sort an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
Array (  
 [146] => Post Object ( 
 [ID] => 5664  
 [post_author] => 8  
 [post_date] => 2016-04-10 16:21:55  
 [post_content] =>
 )  

 [145] => Post Object (  
 [ID] => 5638  
 [post_author] => 7  
 [post_date] => 2016-03-17 12:23:00  
 [post_content] =>
 )
)
```

I want to order my array by the numbers before *"=> Post Object"*.

i.e. I want that the sub-array 145 appear before 146.

Thanks

Comment: Use PHP's [ksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) function.... learn to use PHP's documentation, and you won't need to ask basic questions like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ksort function.

```
ksort($array);
```

For others behaviour read the related documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php